Am I misusing my reopening privilege?
The discussion I would like to have here is about trying to help moderate and about making mistakes and about misusing privileges and perhaps a bit just about being picky about wording in comments. It is not about whether one particular question should be closed or not.
Let me explain the case:
This question What is the type of a constructor? had been closed as duplicate of this one Does a constructor has a "type" in C++ since it is a special member function. After rereading both questions and all answers I was not convinced. [... ..reasons I came to the conclusion to reopen...] Considering all that I decided to reopen the question. Immediately I have been accuesed of misuse. In the meantime I realized my reasons to reopen were misguided and I closed the question again. Though the question I want to ask here persists. Also the user initially closing the question agrees that we should have a  discussion about my "misuse":

@463035818_is_not_an_ai No, there is a need for discussion. You've clearly misused reopening closed question power here. –
user12002570
Commented 9 mins ago

Am I misusing my reopen privilege? Is making a mistake misuse?
Other ways to phrase the same/similar/related (perhaps you can point me to related metas): Is it "ok" to disagree in how to use moderation tools? How should one act if there is disagreement? How should I react on comments accusing me of misuse?

More context:  User reopened their own question when there is a better duplicate that answer the question

"Am I misusing my reopnening priviledge?..." Yes, you are.

@user12002570 no its not a duplciate :D. This question is about whether I have misused a priviledge. The other question is about whether the question should be closed. That are independent questions

I'm not quite following what exactly you are arguing here for the two questions not to be dupes. Are you arguing that the questions are about different things? Are you arguing that the answers are about different things? Are you arguing that the answers are about the same thing but not good enough? Are you arguing that not enough voting has happened?

@MisterMiyagi I am arguing that I came to the conclusion that I should reopen the question and that another user now accuses me of misusing a priviledge. In the meantime I realized my conclusion was wrong (I will close it again in a minute). But I sill find it inacceptable to be accused of misuse. Making a mistake is not misuse to my understanding. I care about not being called a misuser.

I don't think you are a misuser, maybe misguided. As for the other meta post, I fail to see its purpose (other than it being about ego and trying to get your post meta-effect-ed).

@463035818_is_not_an_ai You might want to [edit] this meta-question to clearly state so, then. This is far from obvious right now. (Please also consider to re-introduce the fixes that were made to your text that were discarded by your recent edit.)

@MisterMiyagi I tried to prhase it better. Its close to being a farce, though its not the first time I get accused of purposfully doing the wrong thing and this time the other side explicitly agreed to enter a discussion. So here we are

In truth, I think that the real "problem" is that users shouldn't be able to vote to reopen their posts; the author of a question is biased and has a vested interest in it being open. Being able to use your gold badge to unilaterally reopen your own question, with no attempt to explain why it isn't a duplicate, shouldn't work by design, and when it's not a duplicate issue, users shouldn't be reducing the number of reopen votes required down to 2.

@ThomA good point you raise. Though that would just shift the discussion to the moment 3 users agreed. And then we will have 3 users having misused(?!?) their privilege to vote.

I'm not sure what you mean by that here, @463035818_is_not_an_ai . There's only 1 author of a post. Plus, I didn't even raise the idea of "misuse"; my point was that the action shouldn't be possible.

@ThomA me being the author in this case is just coincidence. This is not a singular case. I have been accused for misuse more often than I can count (mainly for reopening questions, but not particularly of my questions). I agree with what you write, but in any case we need a mechanism to reopen closed questions, and there can always be disagreement on that.

I didn't say that the reopen feature in it's entirety should be removed though, @463035818_is_not_an_ai . I only suggested that the ability to vote to (unilaterally) reopen your own posts should not be a feature.

@ThomA no you didnt. But I say that a mechanism to reopen is a must and no matter how it is implemented users will disagree on some cases. Hence I do agree with your proposal, I just do not agree that this would be "the real problem"

@ThomA I don't disagree with the opinion that OPs have a vested interest in reopening their own questions. How do you feel about OPs using their own questions as duplicate targets? Or if the closer has an answer on the duplicate? Or both, as in this case? It feels like there would be a similar vested interest there.

That's a very different matter, in my opinion, @cigien . It's also actually not a too uncommon event; users that use their VTCs for duplicates are often SMEs (almost guaranteed for "gold badgers") and so have contributed a good amount of content. It's therefore not unlikely that they may close a question as a duplicate of another question where they have contributed an answer to, but, there will likely also be other answers as well.

The answers to the linked question are absolutely horrible. At least the duplicate’s answer actually answers the question that was proposed. The answer to the duplicate also answers the linked question.

Please clarify via edits, not comments, & delete & flag obsolete comments.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai you said "me being the author in this case is just a coincidence" I strongly disagree with this statement, it's the entire crux of the issue.  You are being accused of misuse not because you reopened a question, but because you reopened your own question.

@Craig let's be fair here, it's not misuse to cast reopen votes on one's own question, if it was the system would simply not allow it. Does it make sense that the system allows this to be a unilateral action for gold badge holders even on their own questions? Maybe not, but that's a system flaw, not misuse.

@Craig if you see we specifically have a privilege that allows users to cast close / reopen votes on their own questions.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I'm not saying that it's definitively misuse when someone votes to re-open their own question (or even that it was misuse in this case)---just that I think it's a lot more likely for the accusation to be made.

@Craig what would i gain from it? I think i completely missed the point myself here. Reopen to make my own question collect more rep?

I wasn't even thinking of it as a significant gain, it's just that when you have a personal stake (and I consider it natural to feel a certain sense of ownership over your own posts), people are more likely to question your objectivity.

If you, in good faith, cast a reopen vote on a question because you think it was wrongly closed, that's not an abuse of privileges, simple as that.
If you're wrong in good faith, that doesn't make it an abuse, just a mistake. Those happen.
If you're a gold-badge holder and your question was closed as a duplicate, I do recommend taking some time to try to see it from the perspective of the closer, since you can single-handedly open a question another user thinks should be closed. That's not exclusive to reopening your own questions, though.

"If you, in good faith..." Reopening a question because they think  the answer in the dupe is controversial is not good faith.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai - It's not worth getting stressed over it. There's no point engaing beyond a certain point. Walk away, and you'll feel better.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica thanks. And I will come back :)

Erik A said it really well.
I have one little addendum because I think the key here is in how you chose to phrase it yourself.

I was not convinced.

That really does not have a whole lot of confidence behind it. You can trivialize it away as just a way to phrase it, but in my experience our choice of words usually reflects a state of mind that you may not be actively acknowledging.
So the next time when you are not convinced, maybe ask for confirmation on meta before hitting the button rather than afterwards. Especially if you are yourself the author as that has the tendency to trip more red flags in others; we can witness the proof already, there was a need to create a whole meta post about it and now here we are. It's all kind of a domino effect really caused by a missed opportunity to acknowledge one simple fact:
There is no rush.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai - Having reasons a question isn’t a duplicate does not change the fact the answer actually answers the question. A fallacy that many users make is assuming a question isn’t a duplicate because they asked a question a different way. The determining factor is if the answer, to the duplicate, answers the question or not. Presenting facts not opinions is always acceptable.
